# Can you do math with a column while setting it SQL?

Tags: sql

Trying to increase all prices in category 'TOY' by 3%. Whenever I run the following code it says that the rows were updated however they are all the same price still. Any help?

Code:

```
UPDATE NONGAME
SET PRICE = (PRICE * 1.03)
WHERE CATEGORY = 'TOY';
```

Comment: What is the data type of `price`?

Comment: Price is a decimal (6,2)

Comment: Are you using a transaction and have not committed it? Try executing `commit`. P.S. you don’t need the brackets.

Comment: please tag with db platform

Comment: Does it also say how many rows were updated?

Comment: What is your DBMS? MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server? ... SQL requests should always be tagged with the DBMS, because SQL dialects differ a lot. (But the update statement looks good and should work in about every DBMS. So either the changes get rolled back  for some reason or are just not committed as Bohemian suspects or you are confusing tables or database instances or there is still some other reason.)

Comment: This works just fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3f4c35d0e489680fec16a0521d4740b7